# "Cannot bind to socket on endpoint {}." error within Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

When binding to Memgraph I get the error `Cannot bind to socket on endpoint {}`. How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the specified port (the default port Memgraph runs on is `7687`) isn't being used by another process or that you haven't already started another Memgraph instance on the same port.